# growth of/ growth in

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I know both versions are used, but are they interchangable? If not, when do we use which one? Let's take this sentence:

> A sudden **growth of** child's popularity might be disturbing for their emotional development.
>
> A sudden **growth in** child's popularity might be disturbing for their emotional development.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, either will do.

There is a problem with these sentences, though: *child* is a countable noun, so it needs an article. It's not talking about a specific, known child, so the article should be indefinite: *a child's popularity*.

Comment: No, that's not true. You could also use the noun attributively, and rephrase the sentence to something like this: *A sudden growth [in / of] **child popularity** might be disturbing to* ***adolescent emotional development.*** With that, *child* is not used as a countable noun, and it doesn't need an article. The most minimal change is certainly to add an article to what's already there—but *child* doesn't *have* to be a countable noun.

Comment: @JasonBassford: How about "a countable noun phrase"? *Child popularity* doesn't seem as good to me, because it would usually mean the popularity of children in general, and I think the sentence is talking about a change in one child's popularity.

Comment: There isn't any context for the sentence, so it's hard to say what the intent is. Personally, I don't see it as discussing a single child. (It could be though.) But it certainly does need to be edited one way or the other.